# Add tick label without grid line on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add a tick label on the y-axe but I don't want a grid line in this tick.

When I append a tick to the y-axe it append the grid line and the label. I want to have grid lines and labels for example on 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... then I want to add a label on 3.14 but not a grid line (because I added an axhline which end on a point in the function)

[I want a label on the y-axe at the red line position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7TVW.png)

[But I don't want to appear the gray grid-line on that label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pflij.png)

Comment: I think you need to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: You can use minor ticks, `ax.set_xticks([3.14], minor=True)`.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I can use it, it is no a general solution but I think it don't exist or it is no easy to do.

Comment: @swatchai you can tell the problem instead of say nothing

Comment: @Bazingaa I haven't a relevant code useful to solve this problem, the code to do the line or the graph is irrelevant to find a solution to the problem, the solution can be apply to any graph sample.

Comment: @SirGalan: I've already said something that helps you now and in the long run. Someone even gives you a down vote when he/she sees there was no proper attempt on your part.

Comment: @swatchai Can you tell me the error on the post?